# SharePoint 2010 - User Photos and Sub Directorys

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I open the user photo directory on my SharePoint 2010 in the Explorer.
http://mysharepoint.de/User Photos/Profilbidler (Because it is German)
I can see per user in the root directory 3 pictures in 3 different resolutions (32, 96, 144)

But there are also 2 hidden directorys in this folder (_t and _w)

In this folders are also 3 pictures with the resultions (32, 96, 144) from the same picture in the root directory.

The name from a picture in the root directory is

- Domain_UserName_LThumb.jpg
- Domain_UserName_MThumb.jpg
- Domain_UserName_SThumb.jpg

In both sub directorys:

- Domain_UserName_LThumb.jpg.jpg
- Domain_UserName_MThumb.jpg.jpg
- Domain_UserName_SThumb.jpg.jpg

What is the reason for the directorys _w and _t?
Are they necessary for the User Photos or only present because it is a SharePoint Photo Gallery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a part of a SharePoint Picture Library. The images in the _w directory are the Preview images, while the images in the _t directory are the Thumbnail images.

For more information, see [Where a Picture Library Thumbnails stored?](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/05/27/where-a-picture-library-thumbnails-stored/)